# Error message 'Side-by-side configuration is incorrect' for a Visual Studio 2008 project

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vcredist

Me and my friend are trying to develop software in Visual C++ 2008 Express. We have build a setup file using [Inno Setup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inno_Setup). We are using *Release* build to create the setup file. But the problem is, the setup file is working fine on my PC and my friend's PC. But we have also tried to set up the software on other two PCs. The software is installed successfully, but when we tried to run the software this message came out:

[image]

So we have tried to fix it. From the command prompt (as we find from the Internet) we wrote "sfc/scannow", but it is not solved. We are using redistributables 2008, 2008 SP1, and 2005.

[image]

From the Internet we find out that, if we change 'Solution properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation ---> Runtime Library' from **Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)** to **1. Multi-threaded (/MT) or 2. Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)** it may help. But when we change it and try to build the solution in **Release Win32**, it failed. It says that:

> 1>cl : Command line error D8016 : '/MT' and '/clr' command-line options are incompatible

I think the problem is with redistributables 2008, 2008 SP1, and 2005. If it is true, how do I find out the right version 'redist 2008, 2008 sp1 & 2005' for my solution?

Or, if it is not true then, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: You shouldn't be linking with the Debug runtimes. Did you build from the Release configuration?

Comment: yes. 'Release Win32' @RogerRowland

Comment: Do you really need the `/clr`?  Unless your C++ code calls into other DotNet assemblies, I think you can get rid of it, which will simplify things considerably.

Comment: And beware of `/MT` or `/MTd`: if you use them, you cannot free memory in a DLL other than the one where it was allocated.

Comment: i need `/clr`. is it impossible to solve my problem with `/clr` ? @JamesKanze

Comment: @Shoshi I don't know.  In the work I do, we avoid `/clr`.